# how to create five instances of an object in java such that when there is reference to that object, those five instances should be like object pool?

Tags: java, singleton

How to create five instances of an object in java?

How to create five instances of an object in java such that when there is reference to that object, those five instances should be like object pool? As in singleton pattern, only one object is present, there should be five object instances.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: You want to constrain the number of instances to five?  Put them in a list, and check the size of the list before adding a new instance.  Grab an (unused) instance from the list when you need one.  Maintain a variable for each instance in the list that indicates whether the instance is being used or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's basically the definition of an enum:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE
}
```

ONE, TWO, etc. are the only five possible instances of `MyEnum`.

Comment: This is the answer to the question that was asked??